# Can limits be broken into parts?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I know that $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$doesn't necessarily equal $f(\frac{x}{y})$. But I was wondering for instance when solving for the limit as x approaches 9 of f(x) where
$ f(x) = \frac{3 - \sqrt{x}}{9-x}$, the numerator becomes closer and closer to 0, as does the denominator. So then how come the limit isn't 0. I thought that if $ \lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = \frac{3 - \sqrt{x}}{9-x} = n$, then $\frac{\lim_{x \to 9} f(x) = 3 - \sqrt{x}}{\lim_{x \to 9} f(x) = 9 - x}$ would also equal $n$. Why isn't that true?

Comment: A small correction: We say we *compute* or *determine* or *evaluate* the limit. We don't say we "solve" the limit. Using the mathematical language precisely impacts your understanding!

Comment: I think you mean "$x\to 9$" rather than "$x\to 0$" in the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is partly correct. The limit of the ratio is indeed equal to the ratio of the limits--provided that all limits involved exist and that the limit in the denominator isn't zero (so that the division makes sense; remember that division by zero is not defined).

So you can see that the difficulty here is that you have division by zero, which means the "theorem" doesn't apply.